# Mutliversion IKVM Collision

Tags: .net, ikvm

I would like to use POSTagger by Stanford and TikaOnDotNet when I am developing a .Net project. POSTagger requires IKVM 8.1 while TikaOnDotNet needs IKVM 7.4. Though I include them in different projects in VS2015, when I build the whole solution, the dll files of two versions collide, and the program throwed a runtime exception.

Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

TikaOnDotnet has been updated since version 1.12 to use the latest IKVM nuget. https://kevm.github.io/tikaondotnet/